# Minimum value of a complex function

Tags: complex-numbers

What is the minimum value of $|z+2+i|+|z-2-i|+|3-z|+|2-z|?\;\;$ 
$2, 3, 5, 6$

I was trying to solve this problem by assuming $z= r(\cos x+i\sin x)$ but then the calculations become lengthy and complicated. Can someone help me please?

Comment: $z = x + i y$ and then try to simplify.

Comment: Is it a multiple choice type of question? Where $2,3,5,6$ are the possible choices?

Comment: The minimum value of this function appears to be $2+\sqrt{17} \gt 6$ where $z = -2$ but I am not sure how to calculate this.

Answer (score 0):

**Providing this is a multiple choice question**

We have

$$|z+2+i|+|z-2-i|+|3-z|+|2-z|\ge |z+2+i|+|3-z|.$$

The minimum of the RHS is attained in particular when $z$ is at the middle of $-2-i$ and $3,$ and its value is equal to the distance between those two complex numbers, which is equal to $\sqrt {26} >5$.

**Hence the only possible answer is $6$.**

Comment: $z$ can be any point of the segment with bounds $-2-i$ and $3,$ not necessarily at the middle.